# parse json with php

Tags: php, json, parsing

I'm a php newb and having some problems understanding how to parse a json api return.  Here is a snippet of the json:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
     "list_name": "",
     "display_name": "",
     "updated": "",
     "bestsellers_date": "",
     "published_date": "",
     "isbns": [
      {
       "isbn10": "",
       "isbn13": ""
      },
      {
       "isbn10": "",
       "isbn13": ""
      }
    ],
    "book_details": [
     {
      "title": "Book author",
      "description": "Book description"",
      "contributor": "",
      "author": "Book author",
      "contributor_note": "",
      "price": ,
      "age_group": "",
      "publisher": "",
      "primary_isbn13": "1010101010",
      "primary_isbn10": "1010101010101"
     }
   ],
    "reviews": [
      {
       "book_review_link": "",
       "first_chapter_link": "",
       "sunday_review_link": "",
       "article_chapter_link": ""
     }
   ]
 },
```

And here's the php I have so far...

```
<?php

$json=file_get_contents('the url for the api return');

// create array
$json_a=json_decode($json,true);

foreach($json_a[results] as $r)
{
echo '

List: '.$r[list_name].'
<br />
Title: '.$r[title].'
<br>
Description: '.$r[description].'
<br />
<br />
';
}

?>
```

I'm getting a return from the api and it's providing the correct value for 'list_name', but 'title' and 'description' remain unpopulated; so, I know I'm not accessing those subkeys(?) correctly.  What is the correct syntax for getting at those elements?

Really appreciate any guidance y'all can provide on this.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

title and description are inside a sub-element "book_details", which is an array itself

should be

```
$r['book_details'][0]['title']
```

and

```
$r['book_details'][0]['description']
```

Just turn your error reporting on in PHP, should become obvious that the indexes you're trying to access don't exist..

update: added the array index

Comment: Thanks - this worked!  Also had success with the suggestion from @PaulAnnesley when I returned the json string as an object.I have a related question - should I be at all concerned about the fact that my php code contains the developer key in the url which calls the api?  I'm guessing not, since all the processing is server-side but am not sure.  Thanks so very much.

Comment: @Doug. Well it's probably a requirement to have the dev key as a request parameter to query the API, isn't it? I don't think it matters in server to server. Use ssl to be safer if you want and the api provides it.

Comment: As you've stated, the key is definitely required for the api.  Just wasn't sure if I should be taking extra precautions.  This has been tremendously helpful - thanks again for the sage advice.

Comment: @Doug. No problems. Note, you should really turn on your error reporting in php.ini or with error_reporting(E_ALL) during development. Indexing errors such as the above will become really ovbious as they'll throw and error.

Answer (score 0):

Where is `$p` coming from?

You want something like `$r->book_details[0]->description` to get the description of the first item of the book_details array.

Comment: Beg your pardon - that's a typo.  Should be an 'r'

Comment: Edited to use object property access as pointed out by @daniels. You should edit the $p out of the question.

Answer (score 0):

[Why is $foo[bar] wrong?](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.foo-bar)

Always use quotes around a string literal array index. For example, $foo['bar'] is correct, while $foo[bar] is not. But why? It is common to encounter this kind of syntax in old scripts:

```
<?php
$foo[bar] = 'enemy';
echo $foo[bar];
// etc
?>
```

Source: php.net

Answer (score -1):

Well, `{` this means that you have an object. i.e. you access it by $var->name
ans `[` is an array so you either loop through it if you have stuff inside or you access the values by $var['name']

Comment: same as @dqhendricks. json_decode(..., true) will return an assoc array, not an object..